# How to have optional library in TypeScript definition?

Tags: typescript

There's a package I'm using in my Typescript node project that is throwing an error whenever I `tsc`

> ❯ tsc
> node_modules/jdenticon/types/module.d.ts:116:43 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
>
> 116 export function update(elementOrSelector: Element | string, hashOrValue?: any, config?: JdenticonConfig | number): void;

The issue is that I'm not including "dom" inside my tsconfig lib, but these functions that are throwing errors are only needed if using in a web browser.

I want to make a PR to change this, but is it possible to either optionally export a function or make the Element tag not throw an error if it's optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around this by adding this to your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
}
```

You can find more information here - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: I did that to have `tsc` compile, but I'm looking to find a real fix

Comment: What version of jdenticon & typescript are you on?